# What is the best way to run emacs under Windows?

Tags: windows, emacs

I tried using the GNU Emacs download, unzipped it and then clicked on emacs.exe, but got some obscure error.

Then I tried Cygwin emacs, but when I press ctrl x ctrl c to quit emacs it thinks I pressed ctrl x ctrl "g"!!! I checked all the key mapping and they work otherwise in Emacs.

Is there another version of emacs for windows that just works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used GNU emacs in windows without issues, at least version 22 and 23. Anyway, you can try [XEmacs](http://www.xemacs.org/) and see if you have better luck.

Comment: I tried XEamcs under cygwin and it works perfectly. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install Vim... or check http://www.claremontmckenna.edu/math/alee/emacs/emacs.html for a guide

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer Emacs W32 http://www.ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html (Link is broken, you can view the [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20150212004620/http://www.ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html), or view the [Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3aupdf/emacsw32/) for alternatives).

It has some nice tie-ins with Windows and will also hook into Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a [Chocolatey Emacs package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/emacs) (currently v24.5.0.20150611). If you've installed Chocolatey, open a DOS prompt as an Administrator:

```
C:\> choco install -y emacs
```

Then you can just run `emacs` whenever you want from the DOS prompt. Emacs binaries get installed to the chocolatey bin directory (`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin`), which should already be in your path if you can run `choco`.

Cygwin is **not** required.

Comment: *Cygwin is not required.* but it better to have installed. Especially because it nowadays comes with `emacs-w32`.

Comment: @gavenkoa I just find that Cygwin adds an extra layer. If it's only available in Cygwin then great use it. However if you've got a natively compiled version it makes sense to use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the environment variable `CYGWIN=tty` before launching Cygwin (e.g. from Windows' System Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables) your probem will be fixed and you will be able to kill (more?) Cygwin programs with Ctrl-C. However, it will break console IO for some Windows programs under Cygwin (and ability to kill *them* with Ctrl-C). I haven't found a way to solve both problems simultaneously.